# How to integrate or use docusign(api) using django?

Tags: python, django, docusignapi

I have done one small app using Django. Now, i'm trying to integrate docusign to my app.I have undergone through this url : https://github.com/peopledoc/django-docusign/tree/master/demo but it's not working .Any suggestions please?

Comment: Have you tried their [documentation](https://django-docusign.readthedocs.org)?

Comment: Tried that link but unable to send mail with document( with signatures ) to recipient.Any suggestions please

Comment: Well, I ended up creating my own version in Django. Maybe you can try that too

Comment: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-please-mr-postman/ this link found useful somewhat

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/quickstart-request-signature-embedded   this link too

Answer (score 0):

Since Django is open source and it's based on python, you could build it yourself, add our Python SDK and make the API calls this way. Our Python SDK is also open sourced here - https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client